# How do I return a custom object in Powershell that's formatted as a table?

Tags: powershell

I'm pretty new to powershell, so I won't be surprised at all if I'm going about this all wrong. I'm trying to create a function that, when executed, prints results formatted as a table. Maybe it would even be possible to pipe those results to another function for further analysis.

Here's what I have so far. This is a simple function that iterates through a list of paths and collects the name of the directory and the number of items in that directory, putting the data in a hashtable, and returning an array of hashtables:

```
function Check-Paths(){
  $paths = 
    "C:\code\DirA",
    "C:\code\DirB"
  $dirs = @()
  foreach ($path in $paths){
      if (Test-Path $path){
        $len = (ls -path $path).length
      }
      else{
        $len = 0
      }
      $dirName = ($path -split "\\")[-1]
      $dirInfo = @{DirName = $dirName; NumItems = $len}
      $dirs += $dirInfo
  }
  return $dirs

}
```

That seems straightforward enough. However, when I go run the command, this is what I get:

```
PS > Check-Paths

Name                           Value
----                           -----
DirName                        DirA
NumItems                       0
DirName                        DirB
NumItems                       0
```

What I *want* is this:

```
DirName                       NumItems
-------                       --------
DirA                          0
DirB                          0
```

I could just hack my function to use a `write` statement, but I think there must be a much better way to do this. Is there a way to get the data formatted as a table, even better if that can be such that it can be piped to another method?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

How 'bout using

```
return new-object psobject -Property $dirs
```

That would return an object whose properties match the items in the hashtable.  Then you can use the built-in powershell formatting cmdlets to make it look like you want.  since you only have 2 properties, it will be formatted as a table by default.

EDIT:  Here's how the whole thing would look (After the various suggestions):

```
function Check-Paths(){
  $paths = 
    "C:\code\DirA",
    "C:\code\DirB"
  $dirs = @()
  foreach ($path in $paths){
      if (Test-Path $path){
        $len = (ls -path $path).length
      }
      else{
        $len = 0
      }
      $dirName = ($path -split "\\")[-1]
      new-object psobject -property  @{DirName = $dirName; NumItems = $len}
  }
}
```

Comment: Since it's already a hash table, using new-object is perfect, but it seems like you'd want to move that up inside the loop, and lose the return, so it outputs one object per path.

Comment: Good point.  I forgot the code was accumulating them.  I'd put the `new-object` (without the return) in place of the line with `$dirs +=` and then omit the return at the end.

Comment: @MikeShepard what does your finished function look like? I've tried putting together your answer with the suggestions in the comments, but I can't seem to come up with something that works.

Comment: @Mike that works great! I'm amazed that by simply calling `new-object` within the `foreach` loop, it's able to put the items in a collection *and* return the collection. That feels like a lot of magic to me.

Comment: It's implicitly doing a write-object (which it does for every statement that you don't "consume" the result).  All of the stuff in the output stream is the "return" of the function.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a one liner that will give you the number of children for each folder.

```
"C:\code\DirA", "C:\code\DirB" | ? {Test-Path $_} | Get-Item | select -property Name, @{ Name="NumOfItems" ; Expression = {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count} }
```

It passes an array of strings to `Where-Object` to select the ones that exist. The path strings that exist are passed to `Get-Item` to get the FileSystemObjects which get passed to `Select-Object` to create `PSCustomObject` objects. The PSCustomObjects have two properties, the name of the directory and the number of children.

If you want the outputted table columns closer together you can pipe the above to: `Format-Table -AutoSize`

Example usage and output:

```
dir | ? {$_.PsIsContainer} | select -property Name, @{ Name="NumOfItems" ; Expression = {$_.GetFileSystemInfos().Count} } | Format-Table -AutoSize

Name         NumOfItems
----         ----------
Desktop              12
Favorites             3
My Documents          3
Start Menu            2
```

Comment: You don't need `$_` to `gi`, just `gi` would do. And maybe just remove the `test-path` and do `gi -ea silentlycontinue` and `Name` should have been `DirName`

Comment: @manojlds I figured Name was good enough. Less code yields the same result, a field showing the directories name. I would of started out with DirectoryInfo's in the first place but I just modeled it after what the original script was doing.

Comment: I meant  - `c:\test | gi`. Remove the foreach-object. `gi` take pipeline input right, so there is no need to wrap it with foreach. But once you do wrap it, you have to supply the `$_`

Comment: @manojlds $_ is required for `Get-Item`. Just `| % {Get-Item} |` doesn't work. Unless I remove `ForEach-Object`... Which I like better :-)