# How to get via Powershell AD computer owner attributes like email and account name?

Tags: json, powershell, active-directory

I have a computers that have assigned to users as managedby, I want to get list in JSON format where hostname is a key, and user attributes are values.

But I stuck to get that in one command :/ and put that in json, so use csv for a while.

I run these 2 commands succesfuly:

1. `Get-ADComputer -Filter * -property managedby | select name, managedby > C:\Windows\Temp\computerowners.csv`
2. `Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase 'CN=My User,DC=example,DC=com' -Properties SamAccountName | Format-Table -Property Name, samaccountname, userprincipalname -AutoSize`

where search base is managedby value from first one.

I expect to have output like that:
hostname, name, samaccountname, userprincipalname

I try to combine above 2 commands like that:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -property managedby | foreach {get-aduser -Filter * -SearchBase $managedby -Properties name, samaccountname, userprincipalname} | select name, samaccountname, userprincipalname > C:\Windows\Temp\computerowners.csv
```

but it want work - as not pickup managedby properly as I understand... any help with saving that in json will be more than welcome.

Comment: `$managedby` -> `$_.managedby`

Comment: ok, dont know that I can do that such way... thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't define the variable `$managedby` that you use in the `ForEach-Object` loop, hence the variable is `$null`. You need to use the *property* `ManagedBy` of the current object in the pipeline (`$_.ManagedBy`).

With that said, you're making the whole thing way more complicated than it needs to be. PowerShell can do a lot of the heavy lifting for you if you allow it to. `Get-ADUser` can read from the pipeline, so all you need to do is pass the owner's distinguished name. You also don't need to explicitly specify the properties `Name`, `SamAccountName` and `UserPrincipalName`, because `Get-ADUser` returns them by default. Plus, since you want CSV output anyway, use `Export-Csv` instead of the redirection operator.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property managedby |
  Select-Object -Expand ManagedBy |
  Get-ADUser |
  Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName |
  Export-Csv C:\Windows\Temp\computerowners.csv -NoType
```

To include the computername in the output adjust the above code as follows:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property managedby |
  ForEach-Object {
    $computer = $_.Name
    if ($_.ManagedBy) { Get-ADUser $_.ManagedBy } else { '' }
  } |
  Select-Object @{n='ComputerName';e={$computer}}, Name, SamAccountName,
                UserPrincipalName |
  Export-Csv C:\Windows\Temp\computerowners.csv -NoType
```

---

To get a datastructure that can be exported to JSON using the computername as the key for the nested user attributes a different approach would be more elegant, though. Collect all relevant user attributes in a hashtable with the computername as the key:

```
$computers = @{}
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property managedby | ForEach-Object {
  $computers[$_.Name] = if ($_.ManagedBy) {
    Get-ADUser $_.ManagedBy | Select-Object Name, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName
  } else {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{
      Name              = ''
      SamAccountName    = ''
      UserPrincipalName = ''
    }
  }
}
```

Then create an object from that hashtable and convert it to JSON:

```
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property $computers | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: Hm... Will this select the hostname?

Comment: @Tomalak Not yet.

Comment: OK, I'm curious. The [pscustomobject] method in my answer is a bit clunky.

Comment: Also, since I'm not too sure about that: Is there any penalty for calling `Get-ADUser` on an empty property, in other words, is the `if` in my answer useful or not?

Comment: Ah, that one also good! But i need a hostname :) but I has little experience with powershell before so think as a programmer. Thanks!

Comment: @Tomalak Now it does.

Comment: aha! Now its close to that I was initialy thinking to have :) thanks

Comment: Its drop me an error: Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Identity'. The argument is null or an element of the argument 
collection contains a null value.
At D:\DataShare\Powershell\get-laptop-owner.ps1:3 char:36
+   $computers[$_.Name] = Get-ADUser $_.ManagedBy | Select-Object Name, SamAccount ...
+                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetAD 
   User

Comment: @GorodeckijDimitrij Then you have computers that don't have an owner assigned to them. How do you want to handle those? Ignore? Use a default value? Which?

Comment: for me its ok to comes them as null, as they can be filled later. I will run that script from puppet to suck it in...

Comment: super! I just replace = ' ' to = $null and its perfect!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Happy new year! :)

Comment: @Tomalak About the penalty: I'm not sure. Using an empty property fails on Server 2008 R2/PowerShell v2. I would expect it to also fail on more recent versions, although I seem to recall seeing statements fail in Server 2008 R2 while working without error on a more recent version. Checking if the property is empty is definitely the safer/better approach.

Comment: Thanks, I thought so too.

Comment: yes, It wasn't work for me on windows server 2012 as well, so that check for null is really needed.

Answer (score 2):

This should get you pretty far:

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Property ManagedBy,CN | ForEach-Object {

    # only query AD if there actually is a manager
    if ($_.ManagedBy) {
        $manager = $_.ManagedBy | Get-ADUser
    } else {
        $manager = $null
    }

    # return a custom object with 4 properties    
    [pscustomobject]@{
        hostname = $_.CN
        name = $manager.Name
        samaccountname = $manager.SamAccountName
        userprincipalname = $manager.UserPrincipalName
    } 
}
```

Note: Any value created in a script block and not explicitly captured in a variable or explicitly discarded via `Out-Null` automatically becomes a return value of that block. In this case, the `ForEach-Object` body will emit a series of PSCustomObject instances.

Use the result in any way you like, for example format it as JSON or CSV.

Related reading

- [How do I return a custom object in Powershell that's formatted as a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540192/how-do-i-return-a-custom-object-in-powershell-thats-formatted-as-a-table)
- Jonathan Medd's Blog: [PowerShell v3 – Creating Objects With [pscustomobject]](http://www.jonathanmedd.net/2011/09/powershell-v3-creating-objects-with-pscustomobject-its-fast.html)